# How to add event to outlook calendar from Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring

Does any of you know any way to add **an event to outlook calendar from JAVA**?
I need this for a feature I have to implement, which requires **email notification of user 15 min and 5 min** before the event ?

If you know a way to do this, It would be a big help.

Thanks in advance.

P.S I can do this with @Schedule() but I would like to avoid running the method every minute.
*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your requirements, you should use the Outlook API, it has requests to create notifications in the calendar and send an email to the address you choose.

[Office API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Createevents)

So with this, you only have to make a REST request to the endpoint in question and you should already have what you want, in the documentation that I have attached it appears how to take the tokens and others to authorize those requests to

Comment: I was looking into the Microsoft Graph Apis. They make this possible from Postman at least. Now all I have to to do is get the Access Token from Front End (since they have it) and use RestTemplate or WebClient to post/get requests to accomplish what I need. You basically need the API that makes the request which can be found here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http and the API which finds the calendar of the logged user: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http